# tail recursion to add element to end of list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

I wrote this simple function to append an element to the end of a list recursively:

```
--takes arguments x and lst and appends x to the end of list
append1::a->[a]->[a]
append1 x [] = x:[] 
append1 x (h:t) = h:append1 x t
```

It works fine.  To practice writing tail recursive functions (which I was not aware of until a few days ago), I tried writing it the following way.

```
--tail recursion
appendt::a->[a]->[a]->[a]
appendt x [] acc = x:acc
appendt x (h:t) acc =  appendt x t (h:acc)
```

It outputs the list I want in reverse.  Why this happens I can sort of grasp but it is still hurting my head.

1. Why exactly does this happen?  Is a general thing that happens when iterating over lists like this?
2. is there any way it can be changed (while still using tail recursion/not using ++) to output the list in the correct order?

Note: This is just for practice

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on your previous question, tail recursion is usually not helpful in Haskell. Here, as often, it has numerous problems: it's less lazy and it reverses the list.

Comment: It is a bit bizarre to focus on tail recursion, since that often has not much added value in Haskell.

Comment: mm, I see.  So this is a general result from using it in haskell and should be expected (without manually reversing it again)?

Comment: Yeah, let's just say I probably should have learned it before in a previous course and am trying to catch up with it without switching back to a different language.

Comment: @floxam: this is not specific to Haskell no, it is just how you wrote your program: each element on the list, you push onto the second list as first parameter, so at the end, the second list is the first list in reverse.

Comment: right, didn't mean to imply it was a haskell exclusively thing, but yeah, thanks.

Comment: Typically, if you think *appending* is an operation you will need, you use a different data structure than a cons list (e.g., a [difference list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_list)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why exactly does this happen? Is a general thing that happens when iterating over lists like this?

You use an accumulator that you each time prepend, so you use:

```
   appendt 1 [4,2,5] []
=  appendt 1 (4:(2:(5:[]))) []
-> appendt 1 (2:(5:[])) (4:[])
-> appendt 1 (5:[]) (2:(4:[]))
-> appendt 1 [] (5:(2:(4:[])))
=  appendt 1 [] [5,2,4]
-> 1:[5,2,4]
= [1,5,2,4]
```

Each item you thus encounter in the second parameter (the first list), you "push" on the second list (third parameter), so that means it acts as some sort of stack where the order is of course in reverse.

> is there any way it can be changed (while still using tail recursion/not using `++`) to output the list in the correct order?

Reversing the output, so:

```
appendt :: a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
appendt x [] acc = reverse (x:acc)
appendt x (h : t) acc = appendt x t (h : acc)
```

but as said before, tail recursion has not much added value in Haskell.

Comment: Thanks, got it. On a related note - would the point about tail recursion not having much added value in haskell also apply to if I wanted to do this using foldl?  Would it run into the same issue (reversed list) and thus make foldr a better choice?

Comment: @floxam: using `foldl` will (of course depending on how you implement it), result in the same issue if you *prepend* to the accumulator. Appending will produce a non-reversed list, but will take quadratic time.

Comment: trying to do it with foldr right now.  Looking at the right associativity of what foldr does...I'm thinking a way to do it would be to have list be the 2nd argument of the f parameter (3rd argument to foldr), have our accumulator be the singleton list with the value we are trying to put at the end of the list, and our function basically just a lambda that does what the list constructor does.

Comment: so something like this? appendr v lst = foldr (\x y -> x:y) [v] lst

Comment: @floxam: but `foldr` is *not* tail recursive, this is equivalent to your first approach.

Comment: right yes, was doing it that way for practice. thanks.

Comment: So naively switching what i did for foldr to foldl gives a type error in the lambda on x. looking at the type signature of foldl, the f argument -  Foldable t=>(b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b. So this says the function's first argument and return types need to be of the same. Right now the first arg is v (a value we want to append to the list) and the return type is a list. Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: appendl v lst = foldl (\x y -> y:x) [v] lst actually does seem to work.  Thanks a bunch

Comment: One thing i am still confused is why foldr and foldl have different type signatures (in the function parameter).  The only reason I can see after staring at them for a long time to have the first two params in the function swapped is because they match up nicer to how each fold expands the list, with the type of the first argument in the function for foldr matching the foldable structure's element type and ditto for foldl and the accumulator.

Comment: @floxam That's the exact reason, yep.

Comment: An oddity: in the markdown preview, `reverse` is bolded in the last code snippet. But in the question/answer view, it isn't. I wonder what's up with that! Does that happen for other people, as well?

Comment: @DanielWagner: See [Inline formatting no longer works with syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408921/246886). It’s a bug, or near enough.

Answer (score 2):

Prepending to the accumulator is efficient, but produces the result backwards. Appending produces the right result, but is inefficient. In this answer, I'd like to show a standard-ish trick to directly (i.e. without `reverse`ing afterwards) produce the right result efficiently. The trick is to make the accumulator be a *function* which modifies a list (e.g. by prepending to it). So:

```
appendt x [] acc = acc [x]
appendt x (h:t) acc = appendt x t (acc . (h:))
```

Before, you would pass `[]` as your initial accumulator; now, you pass `id`. You could, if you wanted, hide that detail:

```
appendt = go id where
    go acc x [] = acc [x]
    go acc x (h:t) = go (acc . (h:)) x t
```

Try it in ghci:

```
> appendt 4 [1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
```